# Adding a list of fragments to a framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Heres the problem
I have a list of horizontal fragments, and I want to add them to a framelayout and display them like a list. However they overlap each other. Should I use one framelayout for each fragment? or is there any tricks?

XML Code

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.fujixerox.internaljobrecord.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Java code

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        //Add the newFragment to fragmentContainer
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, nameFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, jobTypeFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, productFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, configFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, serialFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, CATFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, outgoingFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, oldMeterFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, newMeterFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, refTimeFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, totalTimeFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, buttonFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: did you try to put the fragment element in a ListView?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I have to swap some of those fragment at later time, will ListView still help?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this library for horizontal ListView, which you can override its ListItem to be a fragment as you want it:

https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView